# Replacing first occurrence of text using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I followed an example online to create a batch file that will copy a given file while replacing all of the occurrences of a string. I modified this script so that it only replaces the first occurrence, but now the subsequent lines aren't printed and I cannot figure out why. All I essentially did is to perform a check to determine if this is the first line, and if it is not then it simply echos the line. What am I doing wrong?

```
set "once=1"

if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined once (
        if defined line (
            call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
            for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
        set "once="
    )
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```

Comment: "and if it is not then it simply echos the line" No, you don't. You echo an empty line (`echo.` should be `echo.%%B`)

Comment: What do you want to do with the line `if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF`? and what is the purpose of the line `for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X`?

Comment: @aschipfl `if "%~1"...` - most probably showing a few helpful lines when there is no parameter.

Comment: ...which are not contained in the sample, @Stephan, so I was a bit confused; but I think you're right...

Comment: The lines `call set ...` and `for /f "delims=" %%X ...` can be substituted by a single line `call echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%`, if I got it right... however, the code does *not* substitute the first occurrence, but it substitutes *all* occurrences in the first non-empty line...